# Service Fabric DI implementation from Unity to Autofac and Child Scopes

Tags: autofac, azure-service-fabric

I'm currently porting a Service Fabric DI implementation from Unity to Autofac and I need some advice.

Original Implementation:

https://github.com/s-innovations/S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.DependencyInjection

The Unity implementation late registers two dependencies inside the ActorFactory which and then uses the DI container inside the scope of the Actor.

I'm considering the best way to do this using Autofac.

I *think* I need to create a new ContainerBuilder, and register the two Actor Scoped dependencies using a named scope (maybe using the ActorId as the scope Id ?) so that the instances are scope to this particular Actor Instance.

This is what I have so far:

```
  public static ILifetimeScope WithActor<TActor>(this Container container,
        ActorServiceSettings settings = null) where TActor : ActorBase
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        if (!container.IsRegistered<IActorDeactivationInterception>())
        {
            builder.RegisterType<OnActorDeactivateInterceptor>()
                .As<IActorDeactivationInterception>()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors();

            builder.Update(container);
        }

        builder.Register(c => ActorProxyTypeFactory.CreateType<TActor>())
            .As(typeof(TActor))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Update(container);

        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<TActor>((context, actorType) => {
            try
            {
                return new ActorService(context,
                    actorTypeInfo: actorType,
                    actorFactory: (service, id) =>
                        //     container.BeginLifetimeScope()
                        //         .RegisterInstance(service, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                        //         .RegisterInstance(id, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()).Resolve<TActor>(),
                        {

                            var actorBuilder = new
                            ContainerBuilder();

                            actorBuilder
                            .RegisterInstance(service)
                            .InstancePerDependency();

                            actorBuilder
                            .RegisterInstance(id)
                            .InstancePerDependency();

                            actorBuilder.Update(container);

                            return container.Resolve<TActor>();
                        }, settings: settings);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return container;
    }
```

Any ideas, Comments most welcome! Anyone have a view on the performance impact of resolving the Actors and their dependencies through DI / this approach ?

The complete code is here:

https://github.com/Applicita/S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.DependencyInjection/tree/Autofac/src/Applicita.ServiceFabric.Autofac

Comment: I think this might help me with ActorScoped Containers https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811